# Get entity parent with Entity Framework using lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, entity-relationship

I am in need of a solution to retrieve a parent object from a child using EF lazy-loading. I have 10 unrelated classes that can use the one type of child and as such do not know how to setup a LINQ query for it. I have looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) but this makes me think I have to know that the child is in fact tied to Parent1. In the link, I know a blog has a post, but a post won't have a blog. I do not have this type of solid relationship.

Here is an example of my class setup:

```
public class Parent1 
{
    public int Parent1Id { get; set; }
    ... other properties ...
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Parent2 
{
    public int Parent2Id { get; set; }
    ... other properties ...
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Parent3
{
    public int Parent3Id { get; set; }
    ... other properties ...
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    ... other properties ...
}
```

The child has been created, added to `Parent2` and saved to the database via the `DbContext`.

After this I retrieve the child object and want to determine which parent class it is associated with.

**EDIT**

I have a generic call like this

```
public T GetById<T>(int id) where T : Base, new()
    {
        T entity = _Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        return entity;
    }
```

Then I make the call like this

```
Child childObj = DB.GetByID<Child>(id);
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us how you retrieve the child and demonstrate what is not working?

Comment: @Marco Added edit to question.  After I get the child, I need to find which parent object it is tied to. I get the child by the signed in user.